# one-hot encoding not working properly with logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to train a logistic regression model to recognize handwritten English letters. In my test data I have 74880 images. Each image has 784 pixels. The labels correspond to the place in the English alphabet. For example, A is 1, B is 2 and so on. In total there are 26 classes.

In order to optimize the model I decided to one-hot encode the labels. This means for an image with the label 23 (the letter W) after encoding the label will become: `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]`. However, when encoding the labels I receive this weird error: `ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (74880, 26) instead`. This error does not occur when using another model like multilayer perceptron. Weird fact: sometimes I receive `(37440, 26)` instead of the `(74880, 26)` in my error after running the same exact code again.

Anyone has an explanation? Thanks in advance.

Here is the source code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

def binarize(y_train, y_val, y_test):
    one_hot = LabelBinarizer()
    Y_train = one_hot.fit_transform(y_train)
    Y_val   = one_hot.transform(y_val)
    Y_test = one_hot.transform(y_test)
    return Y_train, Y_val, Y_test


def lgr(X_train, X_val, X_test, Y_train, Y_val, Y_test):
    lgr = LogisticRegression(random_state=999, verbose=2)

    parameters = {
    'solver': ['sag'],
    'max_iter': [10]
    }
    
    clf = GridSearchCV(lgr, parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=2, verbose=2)
    print(X_train.shape)
    print(Y_train.shape)
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print(grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_)
    # Y_pred = lgr.predict(X_val)
    # acc = accuracy_score(Y_val, Y_pred)
    # print(acc)


def main():
    # loading dataset
    with np.load('training-dataset.npz') as data:
        img = data['x']
        lbl = data['y']

    # train 60% validation 20% test 20% split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(img, lbl, test_size=0.2, random_state=999)
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=999)


    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

    # one-hot encoding
    Y_train, Y_val, Y_test = binarize(y_train, y_val, y_test)

    lgr(X_train, X_val, X_test, Y_train, Y_val, Y_test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I recommend testing with small data first. Something you can visually inspect. :-)

Comment: @erip That is good advice. However, the point I am trying to make is that the code breaks. Even with very small test data

Answer (score 1):

You are in a multiclass classification problem. The logistic Regression function of sklearn supports this type of problem **without HotEncoding the Output**. That's why your shapes don't match.

**So use your Y without HotEncoding.** Logistic regression will change the `multi_class` parameter to "multinomial" automatically to deal with it.

If you prefer, you can use these parameters: `multi_class='ovr', solver='liblinear'`. Here you are using the technique One Vs Rest (ovr).

Logistic Regression and MLP seems to work different with multiclass classification, each algorithm is different, so you have to check how they works.